# I tried to build a LWC component to view data but its not working

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I tried to build a LWC component to view data, but the data was not showing on UI. i can't get what was wrong with my code.

Html:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="LDS Lab" icon-name="custom:custom54">
    <div class="slds-m-around_small">
    <lightning-record-form
            record-id={recordId}
            object-api-name={objectApiName}
            layout-type="full"
            mode="view"
            columns="2"
    >
        
    </lightning-record-form>
</div>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';

export default class LdsRecord extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
}
```

Meta File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">  
  <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>    
<isExposed>true</isExposed>   
 <targets>      
  <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>   
 </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: did you get some errors?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to check here is if you are getting recordId before the LDS form get loads, if it is not having blank value while loading then try below.

1. Using getter setters to set the recordId attribute
2. Add a console log in getter if the _recordId is having value
3. If not then use a boolean to avoid lightning-record-form load,
   if:true=attribute
4. And load it when you have recordId in getter.

   ```
   load = false;

   @api set recordId(value) {
       console.log(value);
       this._recordId = value;
       load = true
   }

   get recordId() {
       console.log(this._recordId);
       return this._recordId;
   }
   ```

Please check this post also: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/344045/recordid-is-undefined-in-lwc-quick-action-component